# Vuejs. is it possible to pass a function returned from another function to event handler?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

```
<template>
  <v-list-item v-for="(category, i) in categories" :key="i">
    <v-item-group multiple @update:model-value="selectedChanged(category)">
       <v-item></v-item>
    </v-item-group>
  </v-list-item>
</template>

<script>
  function selectedChanged(category) {
    return function(items) {
      console.log(`select ${items} from ${category}`);
    }
  }
</script>
```

I hope that, in function selectedChanged, I can know which category was selected. But it doesn't work. Vue just called selectedChanged with parameter category.

The reason why I want to do this is that, if I define selectedChanged as follows:

```
function selectedChanged(items) {
  console.log(items);
}
```

I don't know which category was selected.

How to impelement function selectedChanged so that I can know which category was selected?

Comment: This is XY problem. You likely need $event here instead of higher-order functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Estus said in the comments, it looks like what you want can probably be achieved by explicitly passing `$event` as one of your event handler arguments. ([Here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers) is a link to the relevant Vue 3 documentation on `$event`.) The code would look something like this:

```js
<template>
  <v-list-item v-for="(category, i) in categories" :key="i">
    <v-item-group multiple @update:model-value="selectedChanged(category, $event)">
       <v-item></v-item>
    </v-item-group>
  </v-list-item>
</template>

<script>
  function selectedChanged(category, items) {
    console.log(`select ${items} from ${category}`);
  }
</script>
```

Of course, this solution assumes that the `items` you're looking for are emitted by the `update:model-value` call in (what I assume to be) Vuetify. You might need to do some destructuring or refactoring to get precisely what you want.